# Respond with SUCCESS in header reply

Tags: c#, api, httpresponse

I am responding to a GET request from a field device with the following:

```
var reply = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)                
{
   Content = new StringContent("SUCCESS")
};
```

The word appears in the message of the body. But the field device is saying that it is not successful.

From this, I can gather that I shouldn't be using `HttpResponseMessage` but some other means.

The suggested reply needs to look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK<CR><LF>
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2016 11:34:50 GMT<CR><LF>
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2f PHP/5.4.45<CR><LF>
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45<CR><LF>
Content-Length: 7<CR><LF>
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100<CR><LF>
Connection: Keep-Alive<CR><LF>
Content-Type: text/plain<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
SUCCESS<CR><LF>
```

BTW I am using Microsoft for this not PHP, this is from the manual.

Should I be using `HttpRequestMessage` ?

The part I am concerned with is <`CR><LF>SUCCESS<CR><LF>`

Comment: Did you check what your reply looks like currently?

Comment: What do you mean by "the field device is saying it is not successful" ? Is it giving a status code of something other than 200?

Comment: Unfortunately, its a relatively dumb device and I can only get a message saying server reply = No. Part of its design is to keep sending data if the response is not SUCCESS, which it is doing.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin What model is the device, how is it sending the data?

Comment: I checked the reply using Restlet and it shows all of the header values as expected from IIS, but not the SUCCESS message, this appears in the body of the message, not as a header as such. https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmlnI5

Comment: It sends data via a URL as a GET message.I then need to respond with SUCCESS.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin The `<CR><LF>SUCCESS<CR><LF>` section does not appear to be a header, as it's not a key-value pair.


Have you tried making it something like...

`Content = new StringContent($"{Environment.NewLine}SUCCESS{Environment.NewLine}")` to account for the carriage return-line feed that it's expecting?

Comment: I will test that now and let you know...thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't worked. I have checked the headers and response and as far as I can see it looks fine. I will speak to the manufacturer tomorrow and find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the device required a time sync with my server before it could send data later on. So there never was an issue with the response.